# On Android, how to add geolocation intent filter to open app when location is clicked?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have tried adding an intent filter for geo location intent. However Android Studio shows an error: **Unknown attribute android:scheme.**

Here is my code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It seems the error disappeared updating Android Studio.